# Generalised Pythagorean Theorem?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

$|a+b|^2=|a|^2+|b|^2+2 Re(\overline ab)$

Can anyone explain this equality to me? How it is derived?

Comment: should be $+ 2 Re(\bar{a}b)$

Comment: Technically, it is the law of cosines for the triangle composed of $a,-b,0$, with the angle at $0$.

Comment: Yes, should be $+2Re(\bar ab)$, or $|a-b|^2$ on the left side.

Comment: Write $a = x+iy$, $b = p+qi$ and see how each side expands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $|z|^2 = z\overline{z}$. So

$|a+b|^2 = (a + b)\overline{(a+b)} = (a + b)(\overline{a} + \overline{b})$.

Now, apply the distributive property on the right hand side, and use the fact that $2 Re\ z = z+\overline{z}$.

As many pointed out, you'll realize that your original formula is not entirely correct.